# Why isn't month shown on my X Axis?

Tags: d3.js

Can anyone explain why Janaury is not bening shown on my x Axis?

http://jsfiddle.net/bwNj6/

I'm using this to generate it:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.ticks(d3.time.months)
.orient("bottom").tickFormat(d3.time.format("%B"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you don't have any data on or before January 1st, and are calling the domain of the x axis with `d3.extent()`, so the axis stops at your lowest value (January 3rd or something around there). Instead of using `d3.extent()`, you can manually choose to decide to start your axis on January 1st like so:

```
x.domain([
  new Date('2012/1/1'),
  d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.date; })
]);
```

[Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bwNj6/1/)